# Automatically scroll a specific div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Here is a screenshot of my ASP.NET web page.

[image]

You can see that I have a menu on the left side which has a fixed height and is scrollable.

When the page loads and the selected menu is at the very bottom, I have to scroll down manually to find it.

I want the menu to scroll automatically if the selected menu item is downwards.

This code did not work

```
jQuery("#leftmenu").scrollTop(jQuery('#ContentPlaceHolderForLeftMenuDiv_' + '<%= Page.Session["divForleftMenuScroll"] %>').offset().top);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I did not understand your question properly but you can scroll to a specific div by `window. location.hash=#divID` or `document.getElementById('divID').scrollIntoView();`

Comment: You forgot to include your screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
jQuery("#leftmenu").scrollTop(jQuery('#ContentPlaceHolderForLeftMenuDiv_' + '<%= Page.Session["divForleftMenuScroll"] %>').offset().top)
```

I had to write

```
jQuery("#leftmenu").scrollTop(jQuery('#ContentPlaceHolderForLeftMenuDiv_' + '<%= Page.Session["divForleftMenuScroll"] %>').offset.top)
```

Omitted the () after offset()

@karthik I do not want to scroll the whole document since the page has just loaded. I just want to scroll the left side menu.

Comment: You should replace `jQuery('#ContentPlaceHolderForLeftMenuDiv_' + '<%= Page.Session["divForleftMenuScroll"] %>')` with `jQuery('#<%= LeftMenuDiv.ClientID %>')`. It will get the ASP generated id for the control wanted.